# How to use a method that has the same name as a language keyword in F#?

Tags: f#

I was on the way build my App on F#, but now I meet the situation : the library I import to use in F# is too big and can't be re-factor method and compile in anyway to change its method name. But the F# keyword `type` is match with the one I need.
What could I do to use it normally ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape it like this:

```
``type``
```